# How to get count for the non duplicates in column

Tags: pandas

My code to get the duplicates, `how to negate the below meaning`

```
df.duplicated(subset='col', keep='last').sum()
len(df['col'])-len(df['col'].drop_duplicates())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all duplicates, invert mask and `sum` for count `True`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5]})

print (df.duplicated(subset='col', keep=False))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True
dtype: bool
print (~df.duplicated(subset='col', keep=False))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool

print ((~df.duplicated(subset='col', keep=False)).sum())
2
```

Another solution with [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and `keep=False` with length of `Series`:

```
print (df['col'].drop_duplicates(keep=False))
0    1
6    4
Name: col, dtype: int64

print (len(df['col'].drop_duplicates(keep=False)))
2
```